# Can anyone identify this small 1x1 round brown part?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

I have 4 of these unidentified parts and I'm not sure which set the originally came from (stud shown for comparison).

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Those are Wheel 8mm D. x 6mm
[Bricklink.com](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4624#T=C)

In brown they were often used as wheels for cannons on sailing ships or castles.